# Create a back-end database for ios & web apps using filemaker

Tags: database, image, ipad, api, filemaker

I'm need to create an ipad app that has access to a relational database as well a lot of images (which should be hosted on the web). My boss suggested that I use Filemaker, as he has a license for one of the versions.

I searched the web for information on what is the best way to do this but I'm not 100% sure I got it right.

Is it possible to use Filemaker for the following?

- Create a relational database
- 'Host' images
- Run custom scripts (optional but not strictly required)
- Publish all of the above to the web, to be accessed by an ios app (and later an web app) through an API.

I understand the the first three points can be done but couldn't find much on how to publish everything and then access it securely later.

Are there better alternatives?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileMaker Server has a fairly good XML API that supports all operations, including FileMaker scripts. It can be used as is or through the official PHP client. There's also an unofficial Python client for it.

Comment: Which would you recommend to use? (the main focus is the ios app access)

Comment: Well, if the iOS app can parse XML, then it can just GET/POST directly to the XML backend.